# Finding the radius of convergence from a closed form representation of a series

Tags: convergence-divergence

Say we have the following:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \frac{\sqrt{5-x}+45\sqrt{x}}{(5-x)^{\frac{a}{b}}} $$ I have made this up on the spot and by no means is this true. How would I go by finding the radius of convergence by the closed form? Do I just pick values of x in which the absolute value would not yield negative numbers inside the roots? This might be an elementary question but I am rusty.

Comment: It depends on whether you want the sum to converge to a real or complex number

Comment: I'm assuming real number.

Comment: Then you choose $x>5$. However, I would like to ask - what is $x$?

Comment: You mean $x<5$ correct? And don't we go with the absolute value?

Comment: Yes, I meant $|x|<5$ - with the absolute value.

Comment: If we were to allow complex numbers, how would this change the convergence?

Comment: It would converge for all $x$, with the condition that $x\neq 5,b\neq0$.